# Can someone tell me what is this on the overhead panel of the Boeing 777?

Tags: feature-identification, boeing-777

[image]

I found this on the Boeing 777 and it was on the Captain's side behind the speaker.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is the sensor for the “cockpit door decompression-sensing latching system”.  Most pilots I know are not aware of this system as it is not usually covered during training.

I have seen this system tested by using your mouth to blow a stream of air over the sensor. This creates a brief pressure differential which automatically unlocks the flight deck door.

Comment: Very interesting! Does it actually open the entire flight deck door? My FCOM says something about "two hinged decompression panels". It sounds like only these would open.

Comment: Yes, it unlocks the door. The decompression panels are separate items.